# Retrieve multiple most common elements in a list

Tags: python, list

I have the following code, but it only returns one most common element in the list based on the original order - Lila. However, I would also like to print out the other most common element - Alexander. I have tried the max function but it seems doesn't work.

```
list_of_names = ["Kanisha", "Candance", "Lila", "Lupe", "Alexander", "Candance", 
           "Irvin", "Kanisha", "Lila", "May", "Lila", "Alexander", "Ivana", "Alexander"]

def most_frequent(item_list):
    dict = {} 
    count = 0
    itm = ''
    for item in item_list: 
        dict[item] = dict.get(item, 0) + 1
        if dict[item] >= count : 
            count = dict[item]
            itm = item
    return max(dict, key = dict.get)
    
print (most_frequent(list_of_names))
```

Apologies for being a newbie to python. But I have tried different solutions but doesn't work.

Comment: use `collections.Counter` --> `print(Counter(list_of_names).most_common(2))` ?

Comment: @Rakesh What if there's only one or more than two most common elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that `count` and `itm` do not serve any purpose in your code.

```
def most_frequent(item_list):
    res = {} 
    for item in item_list: 
        res[item] = res.get(item, 0) + 1
    n = max(res.values())
    for k, v in res.items():
        if v==n:
            print(k)


most_frequent(list_of_names)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`statistics.multimode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.multimode):

```
>>> multimode(list_of_names)
['Lila', 'Alexander']
```

Comment: That works definitely. Thanks for your help. But is there a way of not using pre-built functions?

Comment: a basic exeplanation and/or a link to the doc would make your answer valuable

Comment: @Tryph I don't think it didn't have any value before, but ok, I added a link now.

Comment: @GeorgeYeung Sure. If you want to stick with your approach, for example, then after counting, you could find the maximum count and then find all elements with that count.

Answer (score -1):

```
list_of_names = ["Kanisha", "Candance", "Lila", "Lupe", "Alexander", "Candance", 
           "Irvin", "Kanisha", "Lila", "May", "Lila", "Alexander", "Ivana", "Alexander"]

unique_list_of_name = list(dict.fromkeys(list_of_names))

for name in unique_list_of_name :
    print('The name '+name+' appear '+str(list_of_names.count(name))+' in liste_of_names')
```

If you prefer a function you can try this :

```
    list_of_names = ["Kanisha", "Candance", "Lila", "Lupe", "Alexander", "Candance", 
           "Irvin", "Kanisha", "Lila", "May", "Lila", "Alexander", "Ivana", "Alexander"]

def most_frequent(item_list,top=1):
    unique_item_list = list(dict.fromkeys(item_list))
    counting_item_list=[]
    for item in unique_item_list :
        counting_item_list.append([item_list.count(item),item])
    counting_item_list.sort(reverse=True)
    print(counting_item_list[:top])
```

in : most_frequent(list_of_names)
out : [[3, 'Lila']]

in:most_frequent(list_of_names,top=3)
out:[[3, 'Lila'], [3, 'Alexander'], [2, 'Kanisha']]